# Algun metodo para no modificar un objeto?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Hola estoy haciendo un curso online de javascript y pues practicando y agregando yo mismo un nivel de complejidad quería ver si no se podía modificar un objeto usando el método `Object.freeze` y pues no se si será un error de javascript o que sera, pero me di cuenta que si se puede modificar cuando lo intento hacer de forma mas profunda

```
"use strict";

const producto = {
    nombre: "Monitor de 20 pulgadas",
    precio: 300,
    disponibilidad: true,

    informacion: {
        pimensiones: "13cm de alto * 5 de ancho",
        peso: "1,2kg",

        fabricacion: {

            pais: "China",

        }
    }

}

Object.freeze( producto );

producto.informacion.fabricacion.pais="Venezuela";
const {nombre, informacion, informacion:{fabricacion, fabricacion:{pais}}}=producto;

console.log(pais);
console.log(Object.isFrozen(producto));
```

Me gustaria saber si existe otro método para no modificarlo de forma profunda

Comment: Es que, técnicamente, has congelado el objeto `producto`, no el objeto `fabricación`. Si quieres hacerlo a todos los objetos de tu objeto, tendrás que recorrerlo y congelarlos uno a uno. O usar librerías que se encargan de hacer precisamente eso, como [deep-freeze](https://github.com/substack/deep-freeze)